# 2.81 missing Volume node - any of them available?

Tags: node-editor

Downloaded Official 2.81 and get same result. Search for "Principled" and "Volume" no result

was trying to follow volumetric lighting tutorial and cannot find any "volume" node.
World> Volume node(any of them) are they missing in Nov 20 blender 2.81?
https://i.postimg.cc/cJKgCyxb/blender2-81-volume-Node.jpg

Answer (score 1):

They are under Shader
[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: helps! ...how would you (spacebar) search for it? I would not have found it if not for your post! thank you!